# How to make Konqueror to be the default file manager?

Tags: kde, dolphin, konqueror

When I press a folder and in most other situations Konqueror is used as I want it to be. However there are situations when I press a file path and Dolphin is opened instead. I am not entirely sure what the pattern is that Dolphin is used, but I think it is when the path is somehow presented as a link. For example in the software [Raccoon](http://raccoon.onyxbits.de/) provides a link to the downloaded APK, but when I press it, Dolphin is opened instead of Konqueror. How do I change this?

By the way, I already did set this:

[image]

It is German, but you should be able to get the gist. "Dateimanager" means "File Manager".

Answer (score 1):

On a typical KDE setup:

```
kcontrol (or your KDE configuration tool of choice) > 
Default Applications > 
Workspace Appearance and Behaviour >
```

from there you can change your file associations to be opened by a specific application.

This won't necessarily be exact instructions for your OS specifically, it depends on your setup - however generally speaking, you should be able to distinguish the default file manager from your KDE config tool.

Comment: I think, I already did this. Please see my question.

Comment: What gives `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`

Comment: It gives `kfmclient_dir.desktop`

Comment: `xdg-mime default konqueror.desktop inode/directory`

Comment: Tried this, no effect - even after logging out and back in.  Tried renaming the "dolphin" file and creating a shortcut to konqueror - still uses dolphin every time I click "Open" in a program, which means a 15 to 30 second wait for it, ever since the last centos upgrade, for which no "downgrade" to a working dolphin exists.  How to get rid of dolphin in KDE entirely - it has always been slow and buggy - now impossible to use?